# Ошибка Notice: Undefined index: send in /var/www/html/file.php on line 2

Tags: php

В общем есть вот этот код:

```
<?php       
if ($_POST['send']){ 
        $item = file_put_contents('price.php', $_POST['sale']);
        }; 
?>
```

Ошибка в заголовке. Через Mamp все работает, на вдс выдает это.

Comment: Ну сделайте проверку так `if (isset($_POST['send']))`, Проверка должна быть на существование элемента.

Comment: @StackOverflow просто замечу, что у тех, у кого ник начинается со "stack" тут всегда постигает очень тяжелая судьба)) обычно баны (правда они не связаны с самим ником) :-)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский А с чем же связаны? И если нельзя такой ник поставить то сайт бы не давал возможности .

Comment: Интересно, сделал проверку isset, ошибки пропали, но данные как не записывались в файл, так и не записываются. На локалке все замечательно.

Comment: @StackOverflow я ничего не писал про "нельзя такой ник ставить" ;-)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Тогда с чем связан ваш интерес к нику? И почему бан происходит?

Comment: Если файл не загружает проверьте форму с которой производите отправку параметра, она ссылается на этот скрипт или в другое место. Так же посмотрите лог ошибок Web-сервера

Comment: @StackOverflow это лишь наблюдение, а не интерес ;-)  вот из недавнего https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/259379/stackflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам выдает уведомление, что в массиве $_POST нет эемента с именем send. Для того что бы его не было нужно либо отключить отображение ошибок, либо переписать код.

Отключаем отображение ошибок, уведомлений и предупреждений. Для этого добавляем в начало файла строку

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Переписать код можно следующим образом:

```
<?php       
if (isset($_POST['send'])){ 
        $item = file_put_contents('price.php', $_POST['sale']);
        }; 
?>
```

Comment: `Для того что бы его не было нужно либо отключить отображение ошибок` - прекрасный совет))

Comment: Можно сказать, какой вопрос - такой ответ. Но все же отладку нужно производить заранее, на тестовом сервере.

Comment: @АнтонСкородумов а что в моем вопросе не так? Я же написал, что на локальном сервере все нормально работает.

Comment: На локальном сервере, у вас отключено отображение уведослений и предупреждений, по этой причине Вы скорее всего не видели данного сообщения. То что файл не загружается, посмотрите в лог ошибок Веб -сервера, скорее всего форма не отправляет параметры, или отправляет не на этот скрипт. так же не стоит исключать вариает, что права на директории запрещают созавать файл от имени пользользователя Веб сервера, или файл создат в режиме только чтения

Comment: Грубо говоря если у Вас Веб-сервер работает от пользователя www - то владелец всех папок и фалов должен быть www, так же в правах доступа к папкам и файлам нужно разрешить чтение и записть для владельца. Чаще всего права на папки устанавливают 755